# Zend Header issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, request, http-headers

I tried setting custom headers in Zend request. I am getting the below error:

```
 Argument 1 passed to Zend\\Http\\AbstractMessage::setHeaders() must be an instance of Zend\\Http\\Headers, array given
```

Below is my code sample:

```
<?php
$request = new Request();
$request->setContent($parameters);
$request->setMethod(Request::METHOD_POST);
$request->setHeaders(array("Authorization: MyAuth $authId"));
$request->setUri($url);
```

I also tried giving the headers in string format. But still I am facing the same error. Can anyone find out what issue is made here in setting headers?

Answer (score 1):

the error says it all, the `setHeaders` is expecting an object of the type `\Zend\HTTP\Headers`.

Try to create the object first:

```
$headers = new \Zend\Http\Headers();
$headers->addHeaderLine('[YOUR HEADER LINE]');

$request->setHeaders($headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$request->setHeaders()` wants an instance of `Zend\Http\Headers()` as parameters. So you can create an instance

```
$headers = new Zend\Http\Headers();
$headers->addHeaders("Authorization","MyAuth ".$authId);
```

or

```
$headers = Zend\Http\Headers::fromString($headerString);
```

Check [this](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.http.headers.html)

Comment: You need to give a complete header string like; 
`$headerString = <<<EOB
Host: www.example.com
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1337
Authorization: MyAuth $authId
EOB;`

Comment: Yeah.. thanks for the solution. It works when we give complete header string.